# Anchor tag text not displaying fully

Tags: php, html, anchor

I am trying to display the entire text in the anchor tag. But it is truncating to 79 characters. How to display it fully.

Example: `<a href='#someurl'>This link text is truncating to 79 charact...</a>`

I am giving text `This link text is truncating to 79 characters` but it is truncating to 79 characters.

Comment: Hello. Could you show us a bit more of your code, some CSS for `btn` and `btn-info` maybe?

Comment: ignore those classes.

Comment: Just to be clear, this works in a minimal example. Just tried it using Firefox.

Comment: @SaravananDS Then good luck with your question. From what you gave us, to this point, we can only guess and this is not how Stackoverflow works https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . text doesn't magically get truncated to 79 characters, inside anchor tags, so there must be something else affecting it. Hence my question above.

Comment: Okay. I am not added any specific properties in the class. Is there any functionalities in PHP to remove the ... and display entire text as it is?